# problem renaming command in SIunits

Tags: macros, siunits

I've developed a package in which I want to define a command `\power`, but that name is taken by a command in the `SIunits` package (which my package uses). I initially named my command `\powr` but decided to try renaming the `\power` command in `SIunits` and use `\power` in my own package. The problem is that I've apparently missed something or done something incorrect because I can't get the intended result.

(Note that I don't want to use `siunitx` over `SIunits` at present, although I will migrate to it in the future.)

Here is a MWE which does NOT included all the packages my own package uses. My major problem is that `\square` doesn't work as after renaming `\power` and I simply don't understand why. `\sisquare` doesn't work either but I don't use it. What am I missing?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{SIunits}

\newcommand*{\m}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{m}}

\LetLtxMacro{\sipower}{\power}
\renewcommand{\power}[1]{\ensuremath{#1 \; \mathrm{J/s}}}

\LetLtxMacro{\sisquare}{\square}
\renewcommand*{\square}[1]{\mathrm{#1}^{2}}

\renewcommand*{\squared}{\ensuremath{^{\mathrm{2}}}}
\renewcommand*{\cubic}[1]{\sipower{#1}{3}}
\renewcommand*{\cubed}{\ensuremath{^{\mathrm{3}}}}
\renewcommand*{\fourth}[1]{\sipower{#1}{4}}
\renewcommand*{\reciprocal}[1]{\sipower{#1}{\SIminus1}}
\renewcommand*{\rp}{\ensuremath{^{\mathrm{\SIminus1}}}}
\renewcommand*{\rpsquare}[1]{\sipower{#1}{\SIminus2}}
\renewcommand*{\rpsquared}{\ensuremath{^{\mathrm{\SIminus2}}}}
\renewcommand*{\rpcubic}[1]{\sipower{#1}{\SIminus3}}
\renewcommand*{\rpcubed}{\ensuremath{^{\mathrm{\SIminus3}}}}
\renewcommand*{\rpfourth}[1]{\sipower{#1}{\SIminus4}}

\begin{document}

\sipower{\m}{2} \par
\power{3}       \par
$\sisquare\m$   \par
\square\m       \par
\m\squared      \par
\cubic\m        \par
\m\cubed        \par
\fourth\m       \par
\reciprocal\m   \par
\m\rp           \par
\rpsquare\m     \par
\m\rpsquared    \par
\rpcubic\m      \par
\m\rpcubed      \par
\rpfourth\m

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is not a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) … though SIunits hooks into `\AtBeginDocument` and your re-defined macro gets re-set. You can do the same (`\AtBeginDocument{\LetLtxMacro … \renewcommand* …}`). If you provide a MWE and describe your goal (what macro should output what?), an answer will come soon …

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Looks like the kernel of an answer: care to post one?

Comment: Well, Qrr, it was the best I could come up with given that I didn't know where to begin looking for an answer and didn't know for sure which package was causing the problem (though I suspected `SIunits`). I would have thought the examples make the intended output quite clear, but perhaps not. The answer is indeed to use `\AtBeginDocument` around my renames. I won't answer my own question so if you answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @JoeH The main problem is that we can't really know what the commands should output. I can't see what's the purpose of redefining `\fourth`, for instance, nor why `\newcommand\m{\meter}` isn't preferable to your hand made definition for the unit.

Comment: I always cut and paste examples here and compile them myself to see what happens and I, apparently erroneously, assumed others did the same. As I said above, I didn't know WHAT was causing `\square` to malfunction so I renamed everything that depends on `\power` in `SIunits`. I renamed `\m` to isolate it from `SIunits` because I WAS certain it wasn't the problem.

Comment: Also keep in mind that demanding a "MWE" isn't always practical if one has no idea whatsoever is causing the problem that needs to be solved. Geez sorry I ever asked.

Comment: @JoeH I think I understand why you feel frustrated. Yes MWE might seem weird to ask for a problem that already doesn't work anyhow but consider also the procedure to obtain a MWE; if you start eliminating bit by bit the code lines then you'll end up with an MWE that reproduces the problem in 5-6 lines. So it's a good practice to locate the real offending part of the code. Hence the `W` in a MWE means that this is the minimal offending code (not necessarily compiling) But I can assure you that this is friendly bunch here but sometimes comments sound harsher when written down than intentions.

Comment: As @percusse says, a MWE here is the minimum lines which show the problem, so 'working' is perhaps slightly misleading! ('Necessary and sufficient to show the point' would be I guess accurate if wordy.) The question itself is perfectly valid, and I'll post an answer if Qrrbrbirlbel doesn't.

Comment: @JosephWright I’ll write one up right now. @JoeH The reason I posted such an (unintentionally) harsh comment is that I wasn’t sure what the canonical solution to your problem was (I have never worked with SIunits and as [its maintainer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) is on TeX.SE, he might be more willing to help (and ultimately might have given a better answer than I could) if your question had been stated much clearer). Apparently, though, [he agrees](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88069/problem-renaming-command-in-siunits#comment190595_88069). `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SIunits package uses the `\AtBeginDocument` hook to (re)define `\square` as that macro name is also used by the `amssymb` package for a (graphical) square.

Therefore it provides two package options that deal with this clash:

- `amssymb` overwrites `\square` with no backup of `amssymb`’s original `\square` macro.
- `squaren` provides the macro name `\squaren` instead and leaves `\square` alone.

As the user might load `amssymb` after `SIunits` this redefiniton problem is postponed until `\begin{document}` (after that you can’t load any packages):

```
%%%%%% siunits.sty, lines 75ff.
%%%%%% \typeout messages removed
%%%%%% Comments provided by me           \%/

\AtBeginDocument{%
 \ifredefsquare                           % option "amssymb": \square is overwritten
  \providecommand{\square}[1]{\power{#1}{2}}
  \renewcommand{\square}[1]{\power{#1}{2}}
 \else
   \ifdefsquaren                          % option "squaren": \squaren is defined
    \providecommand{\squaren}[1]{\power{#1}{2}}
    \renewcommand{\squaren}[1]{\power{#1}{2}}
   \else                                  % neither "amssymb" nor "squaren"
    \@ifundefined{square}{%               % if \square is undefined, define it (no amssymb)
     \newcommand*{\square}[1]{\power{#1}{2}}
     }{%                                  % if \square is defined, yell at user:
     \PackageWarningNoLine{SIunits}{%     % "Use either amssymb or squaren option"
     The command `square' was already defined.\MessageBreak
     Possibly due to the amssymb package}
    }  %\ifundefined{square}
   \fi %\ifsefsquaren
 \fi   %\ifredefsquare
 }     %\AtBeginDocument
```

The solution to your problem is to hook yourself into `\AtBeginDocument` and redefine `\square` there.

I also patched `\sisquare` as it is internally defined with `\power` that you also redefine (similar reasons why you need to redefine all those other macros with `\sipower`).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{SIunits}
\newcommand*{\m}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{m}}}

\renewcommand*{\squared}{\ensuremath{^{\mathrm{2}}}}
\renewcommand*{\cubed}{\ensuremath{^{\mathrm{3}}}}
\renewcommand*{\cubic}[1]{\sipower{#1}{3}}
\renewcommand*{\fourth}[1]{\sipower{#1}{4}}

\renewcommand*{\reciprocal}[1]{\sipower{#1}{\SIminus1}}
\renewcommand*{\rpsquare}[1]{\sipower{#1}{\SIminus2}}
\renewcommand*{\rpcubic}[1]{\sipower{#1}{\SIminus3}}
\renewcommand*{\rpfourth}[1]{\sipower{#1}{\SIminus4}}

\renewcommand*{\rp}{\ensuremath{^{\mathrm{\SIminus1}}}}
\renewcommand*{\rpsquared}{\ensuremath{^{\mathrm{\SIminus2}}}}
\renewcommand*{\rpcubed}{\ensuremath{^{\mathrm{\SIminus3}}}}

\LetLtxMacro{\sipower}{\power}%
\renewcommand*{\power}[1]{\ensuremath{#1 \; \mathrm{J/s}}}%

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \LetLtxMacro{\sisquare}{\square}%
    \renewcommand*{\square}[1]{\mathrm{#1}^{2}}%
    \renewcommand*{\sisquare}[1]{\sipower{#1}{2}}% to correct the output of the original square, now sisquare, command
}

\begin{document}
\sipower{\m}{5} \par
$\sisquare\m$   \par
\power{120}     \par
$\square\m$     \par\bigskip

\m\squared      \par
\cubic\m        \par
\m\cubed        \par
\fourth\m       \par
\reciprocal\m   \par
\m\rp           \par
\rpsquare\m     \par
\m\rpsquared    \par
\rpcubic\m      \par
\m\rpcubed      \par
\rpfourth\m
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Because I'm using `SIunits` in a package rather than in a standalone document, I ended up having to use `\AtBeginOfPackageFile` instead, but everything else works.